# Hive Query returned non zero code

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, hql

We are seeing different kinds of error messages(error code: 1,2,3) for the same query using hive. Can someone explain what is this error code and what does different error codes mean ? Please share if there is a proper documentation regarding the error messages. Thanks in advance.

Error:-
java.sql.SQLException: Query returned non-zero code: 2, cause: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask

Answer (score 0):

Found similar kind of post in archive [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11185528/what-is-hive-return-code-2-from-org-apache-hadoop-hive-ql-exec-mapredtask) says "That's not the real error" and here's how to find it:

> Go to the hadoop jobtracker web-dashboard, find the hive mapreduce
>   jobs that failed and look at the logs of the failed tasks. That will
>   show you the real error.