# Error: java heap space on Google Data-Proc Cluster

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

I am running Hive insert overwrite query on the Google dataproc cluster from a table having

```
 13783531
```

records to the another partitioned table without any transformation.
which fails with the error

```
Diagnostic Messages for this Task:
Error: Java heap space

FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from 
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
MapReduce Jobs Launched: 
Stage-Stage-1: Map: 34   Cumulative CPU: 1416.18 sec   HDFS Read: 6633737937 
HDFS Write: 0 FAIL
```

cluster details

```
n1-standard-16 (16 vCPU, 60.0 GB memory)
```

with 5 worker nodes.

The error varies between 
Java heap space and GC overhead limit exceeded.
I tried setting the param

```
set mapreduce.map.memory.mb=7698;
set mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb=7689;
set mapreduce.map.java.opts=-Xmx7186m;
set mapreduce.reduce.java.opts=-Xmx7186m;
```

Still Fails.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is Hive: Return Code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapRedTask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11185528/what-is-hive-return-code-2-from-org-apache-hadoop-hive-ql-exec-mapredtask)

Comment: is your table table in parquet format?

Comment: @lake The table is in text format

Comment: both tables?  if that is the case, could you make sure that the source table files are valid? for example, not a big line with all the data?

Comment: In your example of setting params, you have `java.opts` correctly less than `memory.mb` for `map` but reversed for `reduce`; was that just a typo in the question, or did you actually have them reversed in hive?

Comment: @DennisHuo That was typo thanks for notifying, Fixed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the issue was insert overwrite was trying to create too many small files.
seems we have a fix

```
 set hive.optimize.sort.dynamic.partition=true;
```

https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/89522/hive-insert-to-dynamic-partition-query-generating.html

There are two Solution available both of them worked

```
1. use    set hive.optimize.sort.dynamic.partition=true;
```

or

```
2. use DISTRIBUTE BY <PARTITION_COLUMN>
```

any of these will work.
It is better not to use Solution #1.Seems the JIRA says it inserts records into the wrong partition when used with GROUP BY
that is  why it was disabled by default in the recent hive 
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-8151

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of things you need to address here:

**Total JVM memory allocated vs. JVM heap memory**

The *total JVM memory* allocated is set through these parameters:

```
mapreduce.map.memory.mb
mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb
```

The *JVM heap memory* is set through these parameters:

```
mapreduce.map.java.opts
mapreduce.reduce.java.opts
```

You must always ensure that Total memory > heap memory. (Notice that this rule is violated in the parameter values you provided)

**Total-to-heap ratio**

One of our vendors recommended that we should, for the most part, always use roughly 80% of the total memory for heap.  Even with this recommendation you will often encounter various memory errors.

*Error: heap memory*

Probably need to increase both total and heap.

*Error: Permgen space not enough*

Need to increase the off-heap memory which means you might be able to decrease the heap memory without having to increase the total memory.

*Error: GC overhead limit exceeded*

This refers to the amount of time that the JVM is allowed to garbage collect.  If too little space is received in a very long time, then it will proceed to error out.  Try increasing both total and heap memory.

Comment: I did the required changes between the heap memory and JVM memory but looks like the changes doesn't reflect in the DataProc cluster , the config remain same as they were while setting up the cluster.
Is there any way we can update the configs by setting that up in job level.?

Comment: These configuration will change your Hive memory configurations.  If you are you using **Tez** or something other similar query engine, then you'll have to refer to that query engine's documentation to determine what parameters you need set.