# Hive Map-Join configuration mystery

Tags: hive, query-optimization, hiveql, mapjoin, hive-configuration

Could someone clearly explain what is the difference between

```
hive.auto.convert.join
```

and

```
hive.auto.convert.join.noconditionaltask
```

configuration parameters?

Also these corresponding size parameters:

```
hive.mapjoin.smalltable.filesize
```

and

```
hive.auto.convert.join.noconditionaltask.size
```

My observation is when running on Tez, Map-Join works when  `hive.auto.convert.join.noconditionaltask.size` is set to high enough value even when `hive.mapjoin.smalltable.filesize` is set less than the size of the small table.

Why do we need both

`hive.auto.convert.join` and `hive.auto.convert.join.noconditionaltask`?

The [Apache documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/MapJoinOptimization) is very confusing.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

These parameters are used to make decision on when to use `Map Join` against `Common join` in hive, which ultimately affects query performance at the end.

`Map join` is used when one of the join tables is small enough to fit in the memory, so it is very fast. here's the explanation of all parameters:

**`hive.auto.convert.join`**

When this parameter set to `true`, Hive will automatically check if the smaller table file size is bigger than the value specified by `hive.mapjoin.smalltable.filesize`, if it's larger than this value then query execute through common join. Once auto convert join is enabled, there is no need to provide the map join hints in the query.

**`hive.auto.convert.join.noconditionaltask`**

When three or more tables are involved in join, and

`hive.auto.convert.join = true` - Hive generates three or more map-side joins with an assumption that all tables are of smaller size.

`hive.auto.convert.join.noconditionaltask = true`, hive will combine three or more map-side joins into a single map-side join if size of n-1 table is less than 10 MB. Here size is defined by `hive.auto.convert.join.noconditionaltask.size`.

**`hive.mapjoin.smalltable.filesize`**

This setting basically the way to tell optimizer the definition of small table in your system. This value defines what is small table for you and then when query executes based on this value it determines if join is eligible to convert into `map join`.

**`hive.auto.convert.join.noconditionaltask.size`**

The size configuration enables the user to control what size table can fit in memory. This value represents the sum of the sizes of tables that can be converted to hashmaps that fit in memory.

Here's the very good explanation link which includes description for all 4 parameters with an example:

http://www.openkb.info/2016/01/difference-between-hivemapjoinsmalltabl.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for this link and explanation!

Comment: How can I decide the maximum size I can give to the property `hive.mapjoin.smalltable.filesize`