# FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask (state=08S01,code=2)

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, mapreduce

I am not able to use SQL count query in hive, getting this below error

```
hive> select count(*) from test;

Usage: hadoop fs [generic options] -chgrp [-R] GROUP PATH...
WARNING: Hive-on-MR is deprecated in Hive 2 and may not be available in the future versions. Consider using a different execution engine (i.e. spark, tez) or using Hive 1.X releases.
Query ID = Dayanand Baligar_20191219014045_15170c53-6a45-45f3-a857-52a10837bd3a
Total jobs = 1
Launching Job 1 out of 1
Number of reduce tasks determined at compile time: 1
In order to change the average load for a reducer (in bytes):
  set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=<number>
In order to limit the maximum number of reducers:
  set hive.exec.reducers.max=<number>
In order to set a constant number of reducers:
  set mapreduce.job.reduces=<number>
Job running in-process (local Hadoop)
2019-12-19 01:40:48,560 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%
Ended Job = job_local2087281605_0002 with errors
01:40:48.563 [HiveServer2-Background-Pool: Thread-85] ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task - Ended Job = job_local2087281605_0002 with errors
Error during job, obtaining debugging information...
01:40:48.568 [Thread-73] ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task - Error during job, obtaining debugging information...
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
01:40:48.581 [HiveServer2-Background-Pool: Thread-85] ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver - FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
MapReduce Jobs Launched:
Stage-Stage-1:  HDFS Read: 80 HDFS Write: 75 FAIL
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 0 msec
01:40:48.594 [HiveServer2-Background-Pool: Thread-85] ERROR org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.Operation - Error running hive query:
org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.Operation.toSQLException(Operation.java:387) ~[hive-service-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.runQuery(SQLOperation.java:237) ~[hive-service-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.access$300(SQLOperation.java:90) ~[hive-service-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation$2$1.run(SQLOperation.java:299) [hive-service-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422) [?:1.8.0_221]
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1889) [hadoop-common-2.9.1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation$2.run(SQLOperation.java:312) [hive-service-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [?:1.8.0_221]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_221]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_221]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_221]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_221]
WARNING: Hive-on-MR is deprecated in Hive 2 and may not be available in the future versions. Consider using a different execution engine (i.e. spark, tez) or using Hive 1.X releases.
01:40:48.563 [HiveServer2-Background-Pool: Thread-85] ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task - Ended Job = job_local2087281605_0002 with errors
01:40:48.581 [HiveServer2-Background-Pool: Thread-85] ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver - FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
Error: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask (state=08S01,code=2)
hive>
```

Comment: You might find the accepted answer here useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11185528/what-is-hive-return-code-2-from-org-apache-hadoop-hive-ql-exec-mapredtask

Comment: Please, provide more information about this